# reading csv file into numpy array in below format

Tags: csv, numpy

> [array([ 0.33333333,  0.75      ,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.
>   ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.2       ,  0.25      ,  0.6       ,
>           0.8       ,  0.5       ]), array([ 1.  ,  0.25,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,
>           0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
>           0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.5 ,  0.6 ,  0.4 ,  0.25]), array([ 1.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,
>           0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
>           0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  0.4 ,  0.75,  0.4 ,  0.2 ,  1.  ]), array([ 0.66666667,  0.25      ,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.
>   ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  1.        ,  0.4       ,  0.25      ,  0.4       ,
>           0.6       ,  0.75      ]), array([ 0.66666667,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.6       ,
>           0.2       ,  0.75      ]), array([ 0.33333333,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.2       ,  0.75      ,  0.4       ,
>           0.8       ,  0.75      ]), array([ 0.66666667,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.8       ,
>           1.        ,  0.25      ]), array([ 0.33333333,  0.25      ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.25      ,  0.2       ,
>           0.6       ,  0.5       ]), array([ 0.66666667,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  1.        ,  0.8       ,  0.75      ,  1.        ,
>           0.2       ,  0.75      ]), array([ 1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,
>           0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,
>           0.8,  1. ,  0.4,  0.2,  1. ]), array([ 0.33333333,  0.25      ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  1.        ,  0.6       ,  0.25      ,  0.2       ,
>           0.4       ,  0.5       ]), array([ 0.33333333,  0.75      ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.25      ,  0.8       ,
>           0.4       ,  0.75      ]), array([ 0.66666667,  0.75      ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.6       ,  0.25      ,  0.4       ,
>           0.2       ,  0.75      ]), array([ 0.66666667,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.6       ,  0.25      ,  0.8       ,
>           1.        ,  1.        ]), array([ 0.33333333,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  1.        ,  0.4       ,  0.25      ,  0.6       ,
>           0.4       ,  1.        ]), array([ 1.  ,  0.75,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,
>           0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
>           0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.6 ,  0.25,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.5 ])]

i got file as reading this but i want in `[[0.33333333,0.75,0.5,1.,0.,0., 0., 0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0. ,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.5,0.2,0.25, 0.6,0.8 ,0.5 ],[....],[....],[....]]` in that format

below is my code please review it..thanks for your help

```
import csv
import numpy as nm
my_data = nm.genfromtxt('ta.csv',dtype=float,delimiter=',',usecols=range(4,31))

data=list(my_data)
#input_data=data
print(data)
```

please give me suggestions....thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the `list()` command.

If I take a 2d array like:

```
In [322]: data
Out[322]: 
array([[120258560,         3],
       [167772160,       339],
       [118948100,         1],
       [ 50331904,         1]])
```

and wrap it in `list()`, I get a list of arrays - one array per  row of the original.

```
In [323]: list(data)
Out[323]: 
[array([120258560,         3]),
 array([167772160,       339]),
 array([118948100,         1]),
 array([50331904,        1])]
```

Why are you using `list`?

Sometimes `genfromtxt` gives a structured array, 1d with named columns.  But it looks like it's reading your file as all floats.  So `my_data` should in the form you want.

==============================

Arrays (and lists) can be displayed in various ways - and custom ones are possible as well.  Let me illustrate with a simple array - working in interactive ipython shell

```
In [6]: x=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [7]: x
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Your original approach - which turns the array into a list of 2 arrays:

```
In [8]: list(x)
Out[8]: [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
```

For a complete conversion to nested lists use `tolist` method:

```
In [9]: x.tolist()
Out[9]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

In [10]: print x
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

Notice the difference between `x` and `print x`.  The latter uses the `str` formatting method of array.  The former the `repr` method. Those methods are defined for each class, but generally `repr` gives a more detailed view.

```
In [11]: str(x)
Out[11]: '[[1 2]\n [3 4]]'

In [12]: repr(x)
Out[12]: 'array([[1, 2],\n       [3, 4]])'
```

The `str` format of arrays omits commas, while the format for lists includes them.

For a structured array (such as created with `names=True`), `()` replace `[]`.

```
In [15]: y=np.array([('a',1),('b',2)],dtype='str,int')

In [16]: y
Out[16]: 
array([('', 1), ('', 2)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Note, this is a 1d array with a compound `dtype`.  You do not index columns, instead you use strings to index fields.

The print (`str`) omits the `dtype`, and looks like a list of tuples.  But note the missing `,`:

```
In [17]: print y
[('', 1) ('', 2)]
```

These 2 `list` look the same:

```
In [18]: list(y)
Out[18]: [('', 1), ('', 2)]

In [19]: y.tolist()
Out[19]: [('', 1), ('', 2)]
```

but there is a subtle difference

```
In [23]: type(list(y)[0])
Out[23]: numpy.void

In [24]: type(y.tolist()[0])
Out[24]: tuple
```

One's a list of `numpy` objects (structured 'records') the other a list of tuples.

Note that when I defined `y`, I use the list of tuples.  That's an important detail.

Comment: when i add names=True in genfromtxt

then it gives me

[ (1.0, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, ...  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.75, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0) (...) (...) (...) .... (....) (1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, ..., 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)]

and by using list it gives [(1.0, 0.25, ... 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.25), (...),... (...), (1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,..., 1.0, 0.5)]

it added "," after row how i will get [] instead of ()

Comment: With `names=True` it creates the 1d structured array I mentioned.  There are lots of SO questions about those.

Comment: thanks...but how i got my values in above format? what i have to add?             Thank you once again... but i wont give "," into values by printing it gives[[1 2 3 5 9 8 10][4 5 8 9 100 555]....[][][]] but i want that in [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,3],[][][]] that format what i have to do for getting in that format? is there any option instead of list?

Comment: I've expanded on the various display methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you...
but i wont give "," into values
by printing it gives[[1  2  3  5  9  8  10][4  5  8  9  100 555]....[][][]] 
but i want that in [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,3],[],[],[]] that format
what i have to do for getting in that format?
is there any option instead of list?

Answer (score 0):

when i add names=True

then it gives me

[ (1.0, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.25)
 (1.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.75, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0)
 (0.6666666667, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.25, 0.4, 0.6, 0.75)
 (0.6666666667, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.75)
 (0.3333333333, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.75, 0.4, 0.8, 0.75)
 (0.6666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 0.25)
 (0.3333333333, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5)
 (0.6666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.8, 0.75, 1.0, 0.2, 0.75)
 (1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0)
 (0.3333333333, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.6, 0.25, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5)
 (0.3333333333, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.25, 0.8, 0.4, 0.75)
 (0.6666666667, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.25, 0.4, 0.2, 0.75)
 (0.6666666667, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.25, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0)
 (0.3333333333, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.25, 0.6, 0.4, 1.0)
 (1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)]

and by using list
it gives 
[(1.0, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.25), (1.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.75, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0), (0.6666666667, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.25, 0.4, 0.6, 0.75), (0.6666666667, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.75), (0.3333333333, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.75, 0.4, 0.8, 0.75), (0.6666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 0.25), (0.3333333333, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5), (0.6666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.8, 0.75, 1.0, 0.2, 0.75), (1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0), (0.3333333333, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.6, 0.25, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5), (0.3333333333, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.25, 0.8, 0.4, 0.75), (0.6666666667, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.25, 0.4, 0.2, 0.75), (0.6666666667, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.25, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0), (0.3333333333, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.25, 0.6, 0.4, 1.0), (1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)]

it added "," after row