# read 2D array with mixed data

Tags: python, numpy

I have data in a file that look like this

```
864 | 85 | '[150, 145, 110, 99, 95, -10] | ....
```

I can read these data as

```
np.genfromtxt(neighbors_file, delimiter = '|', dtype=(int, int, '|S66'), usecols=(0, 1, 2))
```

Which gives me an array with every `line` as a tuple

```
d = array([(864, 85, '[150, 145, 110, 99, 95, -10]'),
       (864, 92, '[160, 147, 97, -22]'),
       (864, 94, '[186, 146, 144, 114, 106]'), ...,
       (3376, 734, '[733, 532, 531, 528, 524, 521]'),
       (3376, 735, '[742, 673, 611, 529, 514, 513]'),
       (3376, 742, '[735, 611, 533, 514, -15, -16]')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', 'S66')])
```

Now I have to iterate over the lines using the indexing `d[i]` instead of using
`d[:, 0]` for the first column and `d[:, 1]` for the second.

Any idea?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: you access structured arrays using the column names for example >>> d['f0']  # array([864, 864, 864], dtype=int64) ...  >>> d['f1'] #array([85, 92, 94], dtype=int64)  >>> d['f2'] # array([b'[150, 145, 110, 99, 95, -10]', snip...  b'[186, 146, 144, 114, 106]'],   dtype='|S66')
>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = array([(864, 85, '[150, 145, 110, 99, 95, -10]'),
       (864, 92, '[160, 147, 97, -22]'),
       (864, 94, '[186, 146, 144, 114, 106]'), ...,
       ...], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', 'S66')])
```

is a structured array.  Notice the compound `dtype`, which is derived from your `dtype=(int, int, '|S66')` parameter.

Instead of the rows and columns of a 2d array, this has records, and fields.

```
 d[0]   # one record, same dtype
 d['f0']  # an array in ints, the first field
 d['f2']  # an array of strings, the 3rd field
 d[1]['f1']  # 92
 d['f1'][1]  # same thing
```

Confusion over what `genfromtxt` returns is very common; there are more answers if this isn't enough.

Technically each 'line' is not a tuple, but a `numpy.void`, a compound dtype element.  It is displayed as a tuple, to better distinguish it from a dimension of a nd array.  See my other recent answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606421/901925

Answer (score 2):

Numpy arrays are by definition not mixed, that means each element in d[i, j] has to be of the type. So there is no way to do what you want. Check the docs for more info at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html

Comment: but see the comments about structured arrays